# reponse.css on not working

Tags: css, scrapy

I just started off with **scrapy**. I've loaded the page `http://www.ikea.com/ae/en/catalog/categories/departments/childrens_ikea/31772/` with `scrapy shell [url]` and ran `response.css(div.productTitle.Floatleft)` to get product names but it gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    NameError: name 'div' is not defined.

How can I fix this?

Comment: you have to use string: "div.productTitle.Floatleft". Now you try to use variable `div`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use string: `"div.productTitle.Floatleft"`.  See `" "`

Now you try to use variable `div`.

---

**EDIT:** to get correct data you have to set `User-Agent`

Run shell

```
scrapy shell http://www.ikea.com/ae/en/catalog/categories/departments/childrens_ikea/31772/
```

In shell you can use web browser to see HTML from server and you will see error message.

```
view(response)
```

You get page again using different `User-Agent` (using `url` from previous `response`)

```
fetch(response.url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

response.css('div.productTitle.floatLeft')
```

BTW: it has to be `floatLeft`, not `Floatleft` - see lower `f` and upper `L`

---

**EDIT:** the same as standalone script (doesn't need project)

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    #allowed_domains = ['http://www.ikea.com']

    start_urls = ['http://www.ikea.com/ae/en/catalog/categories/departments/childrens_ikea/31772/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        all_products = response.css('div.product')

        for product in all_products:
            title = product.css('div.productTitle.floatLeft ::text').extract()
            description = product.css('div.productDesp ::text').extract()
            price = product.css('div.price.regularPrice ::text').extract()
            price = price[0].strip()

            print('item:', title, description, price)

            yield {'title': title, 'description': description, 'price': price}

# --- it runs without project and saves in 'output.csv' ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv',
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Result in file output.csv:

```
title,description,price
BÖRJA,feeding spoon and baby spoon,Dhs 5.00
BÖRJA,training beaker,Dhs 5.00
KLADD RANDIG,bib,Dhs 9.00
KLADDIG,bib,Dhs 29.00
MATA,4-piece eating set,Dhs 9.00
SMASKA,bowl,Dhs 9.00
SMASKA,plate,Dhs 12.00
SMÅGLI,plate/bowl,Dhs 19.00
STJÄRNBILD,bib,Dhs 19.00
```

Comment: Hi friend, many thanks for the response. I actually tried this and it gives me [] as result. Can you help me with this?

Comment: in `scrapy shell` use `view(response)` and you see in web brower what you get from server. it seems it gives message about error or maybe it message for bots. Maybe you will have to set `User-Agent` header (or other headers too) to get correct data.

Comment: I checked with `User-Agent` set on `Mozilla/5.0` and it gives correct HTML from server. But you have wrong css selector - it has to be `floatLeft`, not `Floatleft` - see lower `f` and upper `L`

Comment: By the way, this is for the scraping, now I want to make a crawler. However I cant seem to make the software he is using to make the spider. Can you tell me what it is?

Comment: He uses `scrapy` to build crawler - you can see `import scrapy` in movie. `scrapy shell` is only tool to help/test when you build crawler. Go to official page: [Scrapy.org](https://scrapy.org/), and read all documentation.

Comment: see in answer standalone script which runs without project